# Eslint on Vuetify: Variable 'props' is already declared in the upper scope

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

ESLint is giving me this warning on vuetify code that is written according to the documentation:

```
<template>
  <v-tooltip location="bottom" :text="tooltipText">
    <template #activator="{ props }">
      <v-btn-icon-secondary
        v-bind="props"
        :icon="icon"
        :color="color"
        @click="handleClick"
      >
      </v-btn-icon-secondary>
    </template>
  </v-tooltip>
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  tooltipText: { type: String, required: false, default: "" },
  icon: { type: String, required: false, default: "mdi-card" },
  color: { type: String, required: false, default: "primary" },
});

const emit = defineEmits(["click"]);

function handleClick(event) {
  emit("click", event);
}
</script>
```

I am getting the `vue/no-template-shadow` warning:
`Variable 'props' is already declared in the upper scope`

Is there a nice way to fix this, except from ignoring the warning?

I am using Vue 3.3.4, Vuetify 3.2.5, eslint 8.46.0 and eslint-plugin-vuetify 2.0.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ESLint error you're seeing is related to shadowing a variable name, i.e., using the same variable name in a nested scope. The variable props is declared in both your  and the slot props of your v-tooltip activator.

A simple solution would be to rename one of the props. In this case, renaming the props inside the activator slot scope would be a good choice. Here's how:

```
<template>
  <v-tooltip location="bottom" :text="tooltipText">
    <template #activator="{ props: activatorProps }">
      <v-btn-icon-secondary
        v-bind="activatorProps"
        :icon="icon"
        :color="color"
        @click="handleClick"
      >
      </v-btn-icon-secondary>
    </template>
  </v-tooltip>
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  tooltipText: { type: String, required: false, default: "" },
  icon: { type: String, required: false, default: "mdi-card" },
  color: { type: String, required: false, default: "primary" },
});

const emit = defineEmits(["click"]);

function handleClick(event) {
  emit("click", event);
}
</script>
```

In this way, you won't be shadowing the props variable anymore, and ESLint should stop giving you the warning.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is related to the ESLint rule that disallows variable declarations from shadowing variables declared in the outer scope.
In your case, the warning is triggered because the props variable in the `<template>` section is already declared in the `<script setup>` section.
You can rename the variable in either the `<template>` or `<script setup>` section.